# Replace values in column based on condition, then return dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'd like to replace some values in the first row of a dataframe by a dummy.

```
df[[0]].replace(["x"], ["dummy"])
```

The problem here is that the values in the first column are replaced, but  not as part of the dataframe.

```
print(df)
```

yields the dataframe with the original data in column 1. I've tried

```
df[(df[[0]].replace(["x"], ["dummy"]))]
```

which doesn't work either..

Comment: You need to pass `inplace=True`: `df[[0]].replace(["x"], ["dummy"], inplace=True)` see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace

Comment: `df.iloc[0] = df[[0]].replace(["x"], ["dummy"])` should work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` returns a copy of the data by default, so you need to either overwrite the df by self-assign or pass `inplace=True`:

```
df[[0]].replace(["x"], ["dummy"], inplace=True)
```

or

```
df[0] = df[[0]].replace(["x"], ["dummy"])
```

see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas.DataFrame.replace)